# True/False: A subspace is a vector space, and a vector space is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the question asked verbatim on my Quiz:
T/F:  A subspace is a vector space, and a vector space is a subspace.
I put down False, but the answer is apparently True. 
I feel like the phrasing was misleading and/or imprecise. 
Thoughts?
Can someone please explain to me how this is True?

Comment: I mean, both statements are true, how do you feel it's misleading?

Comment: A subspace is always a vector space.. that is a true statement?

Comment: I would say that it is unusual to make the statement that something "is a subspace" without specifying what it is a subspace **of**.

Comment: @ChrisWinig by definition, a subspace is a subset which is also a vector space. So it's in the definition.

Comment: Thank you @Omnomnomnom that clarifies what was confusing to me.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the question was probably deliberately phrased in a slightly misleading way. $$ \\$$

I'll assume that your confusion arose from the second part of the question, i.e., you know that a subspace is a vector space. $$ \\$$

As for the second part: I would not call it a type error but would interpret such a question automatically as "there is a vector space of which $V$ is a subspace". And this is certainly true: namely, $V$ itself.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement is true and the second statement is a [type error](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/the-type-system-of-mathematics/).

The word "subspace" requires two arguments: its grammar is "$U$ is a subspace of $V$," so you need to specify both $U$ and $V$ for the word to make sense. The statement "a vector space is a subspace" is missing $V$: what is it a subspace *of*? It's like saying "brown is the color." The color of what?